# What is future for BizTalk Server in the Market?

Tags: biztalk

I am undergoing BizTalk server training in my company.

I have almost 6 years of experience in both Microsoft and Open Source like PHP mostly in web applications.

Does it make sense to learn Biztalk server for my future career?

In short Will it help me to improve my profile?

Please advise/suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Learning anything that is an active and vibrant technology will help you and your career.  I don't see how this could be qualified as a negative in any aspect.

Answer (score 1):

Even if this particular product goes out of use, it's useful to understand the problems it is intended to solve and the general approach. Don't get too hung-up on details though.

Comment: My intension to ask this questions is, If I have 2/3 options to choose in betn Biztalk server, MOSS and PHP framework...
to whom should I give Priority?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [New Features in BizTalk Server 2009](http://www.microsoft.com/biztalk/en/us/whats-new.aspx). It's not dead yet.

Answer (score 0):

i have been doing BizTalk server development for years and it has most certainly helped me be an early adopter of the SOA / Contract first / Loosley coupled application fad that is sweeping through the industry ... why? well because as BizTalk developers we've always done this stuff. it aint new to us.

so yes, learn it. it can't do you any harm at all!

Comment: My intension to ask this questions is, If I have 2/3 options to choose in betn Biztalk server, MOSS and PHP framework...
to whom should I give Priority?